# How to identify a C-style string in C?

Tags: c, string, conventions

In C, a function may ask for or give a C-style string, or not. Or return it.

How to distinguish a C-style string from a non—C-style string? Is there an idiomatic common way to do this?

Maybe you could use a macro, like

```
#define C_STRING char*
```

It generates the same code, but it tells what type of string is being used.

Comment: There's no way to distinguish it. C strings are defined by how they're used, not anything intrinsic.

Comment: There are no "non-C-style strings" in C. If it doesn't have a null terminator, it's not a string at all, it's just an array of bytes.

Comment: @Barmar, I've seen functions asking for a character pointer calling it "string" in order to return a non—Null-terminated "string", and returning its length using the function returns. So I guessed that "strings" could not have a NULL character at the end.

Comment: There is no idiomatic way to differentiate "byte array and length" from "null-terminated string"; however, the fact that a function _takes_ a length is usually a good indication.  (eg, memcpy vs strlen)

Comment: Those are usually called `char array`, not strings.

Comment: A somewhat serious answer: hungarian notation usually uses 'sz' in the variable/parameter name for null terminated strings, but that's considered pretty old fashioned.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking: Is there any consensus for a convention to distinguish between "this `char *` pointer type is for pointers to random characters somewhere" versus "this `char *` pointer type is for pointers specifically to a null-terminated string".  My answer is: no, I'm not aware of any such convention.

Answer (score 2):

> a function may ask for or give a C-style string,

No.  The C library defines a "string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  A function may receive a *pointer* to a string, but not a *string*.  Like-wise, a function may return a pointer to a string, but not return a string.

Typically this pointer is a `char *` or `const char *`.  Many C library string functions assume the pointer points to a sequence of memory that eventfully includes a *null character*.  If it does not, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

This is no test for "How to identify a C-style string in C?" other than the presence of a null character within valid memory.

We could limit the test based on size:

```
bool valid_c_string(size_t sz, const char *s) {
  return memchr(s, '\0', sz) != NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by a "non—C-style string"? The only strings that exist in C are sequences of characters terminated by a zero `'\0'` byte.

If you are thinking of a type that carries the length of the string with it, like the C++ `std::string`, then this does not exist in C.

Hiding the fact that a C string is an array (or pointer) behind a typedef or #define, is evil, and should be avoided at all costs. Harvard's CS50 please take note.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding pointers behind `typedef` is widely recognized as bad practice. Hiding them behind a `#define` is even worse practice!

This is all handled through source code documentation, not through the actual code. If we look at for example standard lib `strlen`, the documentation goes as:

```
#include <string.h>
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

> The `strlen` function computes the length of the string pointed to by `s`.

This means that the function expects a string (nul-terminated character array) and if you pass something else to it, then you have a problem. This is all in the spirit of C, lots of freedom, lots of pitfalls, program efficiency over type safety. "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot", as one famous quote by Bjarne Stroustrup starts.

---

That being said, there are a few rarely used tricks that could be used to improve type safety somewhat at compile-time. We could have declared the function as `size_t my_strlen (const char str[static 1])` which means that some compile-time checks are made possible: the function won't accept arrays with size smaller than 1 nor will it accept a null pointer. clang (and therefore also icx) has supported this for ages and gcc finally implemented it it too as per gcc 11.